# Spell out numbers or use numerals when in a list?

Tags: writing-style, numbers

So we often get the general advice that we should spell out small numbers and use numerals for large numbers. However, what if you are referring to a list of a few numbers, some large and some small. Switching between numerals and spelt-out numbers. For example, consider the following

> I repeated the experiment five times using five, eight, 10, 20 and 100 mice.

This just looks awkward. Would,

> I repeated the experiment five times using 5, 8, 10, 20 and 100 mice,

be better?

Comment: This is a stylistic choice. If you are writing for publication, consult the style guide of the publication you are writing for.

Comment: The second is perfectly fine – there is no need to be dogmatic about it. I use whatever I think will be clearest, such as "3 three-legged mice." It can't be misread as "33-legged mice", and isn't the odd-looking "three three-legged mice."

Comment: Go ahead with the numerals and also remove "respectively" for being misapplied. Use it to show a correlation: *A and B use X and Y respectively* (because A uses X, and B uses Y.)

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is fine – there is no need to be dogmatic.

I use whatever I think will be clearest, such as *'3 three-legged mice'*.

If I wrote *'3 3-legged mice'* it could be misread as *'33-legged mice'*
and writing *'three three-legged mice'* looks very odd.